# в Html не работает тег video

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, видео

Хочу использовать тег video в своем сайте, но он выдает ошибку мол видео не найдено хотя файл html и видео находятся в одной папке. Работая на pycharm видео не показывается, а когда тестировал на vs code видео показывалось. В чем проблема?